# All domains in Windows XP refer to 1.0.0.0

Tags: windows-xp, ip, diagnostic

Today my mother has complained about issues with the internet connection on her laptop: a few days ago, GMail worked, but today it and all other sites won't load, resulting in a "time out error". The laptop connects to old D-Link G604T router via Wi-Fi and the router is often malfunctioning, so I've rebooted it. No effect.

Next, I've tried to open the router's web configuration panel and it loaded fine.

After that, I tried to load the OpenDNS site with IP address (208.69.38.160), and it worked well too.

Next, I've tried to `ping gmail.com` from the `cmd.exe` and saw a strange thing: ping tried to send packages to 1.0.0.0. It was the same thing for all other domains, too! I've checked the `hosts` file, but no - it was clear.

Now, I'm stuck, because I have totally no idea what should I check/try next. Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Евгения>route print
===========================================================================
Interface List
0x1 ........................... MS TCP Loopback interface
0x2 ...00 13 02 71 e5 22 ...... Intel(R) PRO/Wireless 3945ABG Network Connection
 - Packet Scheduler Miniport
===========================================================================
===========================================================================
Active routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface   Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1     192.168.1.6       25
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0        127.0.0.1       127.0.0.1       1
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0      192.168.1.6     192.168.1.6       25
      192.168.1.6  255.255.255.255        127.0.0.1       127.0.0.1       25
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255      192.168.1.6     192.168.1.6       25
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0      192.168.1.6     192.168.1.6       25
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255      192.168.1.6     192.168.1.6       1
Default Gateway:       192.168.1.1
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

Comment: Can you bypass the router and connect directly to the internet?

Comment: From the cmd prompt, type "route print" and see if you see any routes defined as 1.0.0.0

Comment: @shufler added, but I can't see anything interesting :-/

Comment: @Shinrai no and other machines in the network are working fine

Comment: Betting it has something to do with a captive portal.  Our Cisco WAP redirects all HTTP requests to 1.1.1.2 until the user has signed in to the WAP.

Comment: @ultrasawblade No. This is just a small home network. :) Since my question, the same problem occurred 2 or 3 times more, but every time, it was resolved with the tool **Synetech** has advised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like something changed some of the settings. Let’s hope it was a piece of legitimate software that was installed and not some malware. Either way, there are a few steps you can use to find and fix it (reboot after each one).

1. Get [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902) and run it. In `Options`, select *Verify* and both *Hide* options. Now check the `Winsock` tab to see if there is anything suspicious. If so, disable it and reboot. If that fixes it, you can delete it. (You can also use Autoruns to check for other things.)
2. Try the command `netsh winsock reset catalog` (XP SP2+).
3. Try the [Microsoft FixIt tool](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299357) for this problem.
4. Try WinSockFix<sup>[[1]](http://majorgeeks.com/download4372.html)[[2]](http://www.snapfiles.com/get/winsockxpfix.html)</sup>. This is my go-to tool for Internet connection problems.
5. And finally, a couple more [advanced-troubleshooting](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314067) [guides from Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/811259)
6. If worse comes to worse, you can try uninstalling the network adapter in Device Manager, then rescanning to reinstall it from scratch.
7. Optionally, run a malware scanner or two if you suspect she got infected by something.

Comment: No problem. WinSockFix is my #1 choice for connection problems.

Answer (score 2):

This may actually be a router problem. I see a lot of chatter regarding DNS returning 1.0.0.0 and Linux machines, some suggestions to disable ipv6, and then googling around based upon your router model, I also see some firmware fixes such as `v1.00b05 "DNS Pass Through with DNS relay fix"`

See: ( http://www.google.com/search?q=1.0.0.0+D-Link+G604T )

Answer (score 0):

What is your dns settings?  Do they point to the router or do they go to your ISP dns servers?
This sounds like your computer is getting a bad dns response.

Comment: Obtain automatically -> so it grabs settings from the router

Comment: @Oleg - try entering 8.8.8.8 manually for the dns server.